# how to use “iterator” for call by reference?

Tags: c++

I have defined a dynamic memory as * indexs (vector of vector) to store set of values. Then, I appended this memory. Afterthat, I want to get a print of these values. For that I am using another function as follows. For that function, I am calling above values by references. I don’t know proper way to use iterator to print those values.
Here is my piece of codes and the error I got for that.

```
vector< vector<unsigned int> >* indexs = new vector< vector<unsigned int> >(9); 
for( ){       //finish data adding into indexs      } 
calcParameter(*indexs); //call function 
void myclass::calcParameter(vector< vector<unsigned int> >const &indexs){ 
    vector< vector<unsigned int> > :: iterator cell_i; 
    for (cell_i=indexs->begin(); cell_i != indexs->end();cell_i++){ //this is line 305 in my program
        vector<unsigned int> :: iterator pij; 
        for (pij=cell_i->begin(); pij =! cell_i->end(); pij++){ 
            cout<<"  "<<*pij; 
       } 
       cout<<endl; 
   } 
} 

error message: 305-base operand of `->' has non-pointer type `const 
std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> >, 
std::allocator<std::vector<unsigned int, std::allocator<unsigned int> > > >'
```

when I use simple for loop to get that, It works but I want to learn how to use iterator for this.

```
void myclass::calcParameter(vector< vector<unsigned int> >const &indexs){ 
   for (int i=0; i<indexs.size(); i++){   

        for (int j=0; j< indexs[i].size(); j++){ 

            cout<<"  "<<indexs[i][j]; 
       } 
       cout<<endl; 
   } 
}
```

Any help please..

Comment: Your code is completely unreadable, and you question hard to understand. Please try to make it a clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`indexs` is not a pointer, it's a reference, that's all. You need to say

```
indexs.begin()
```

and not

```
indexs->begin()
```

(etc).

Comment: @hill>> thanks, but it doesnt work. i wanted to know when i have defined a dynamic memory allocation and if i call that memory to a function as a reference input, then can i use iterators to view the data inside the function?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you're asking?